# Regex Python 3.x

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

My string is:

```
s = '"location":{"state":"WA"},"active":true'
```

I want to get a regex expression so I can capture the following:

```
group 1: location":
group 2: state":
group 3: active":
```

Since these 3 words all end with ":

I have tried the following regex, but it is not working:

```
"[(a-zA-Z)*]+":
```

I need to capture via 3 groups.

Comment: I don't think you want to capture in three separate groups, but rather match the regex *three times*. Groups are usually for matching things that you know where they are, to put it simply.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine.

```
>>> re.findall("([a-zA-Z]+)\":", s)
['location', 'state', 'active']
```

Or you can use two steps to complete it.
First, use `re.findall` with `[a-zA-Z]+\":` to find 3 groups.

```
>>> re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+\":", s)
['location":', 'state":', 'active":']
```

Second, replace `":` with empty: `r.replace("\":", "")`

```
>>> res = re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+\":", s)
>>> res
['location":', 'state":', 'active":']
>>> for r in res:
...     r.replace("\":", "")
...
'location'
'state'
'active'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to capture it with a simple `(r'\w+":')`

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '"location":{"state":"WA"},"active": True'
>>> a = re.compile(r'\w+":')
>>> location, state, active = a.findall(s)
>>> location, state, active
('location":', 'state":', 'active":')
```